# Php form not working: 'permission denied to...'

Tags: php, html, forms, email, doctype

I know almost nothing about PHP other than the basics, not enough to understand what I found on the web to make a submission form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assets | Cicada3301's Website</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/stylesheet.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui-stylesheet.css'>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://www.copot.eu/matei/assets/me.jpg'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
$savedata = $_REQUEST['savedata'];
if ($savedata == 1){ 
$data = $_POST['name'];
$data .= $_POST['email'];
$data .= $_POST['message'];
$file = "YOURDATAFILE.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Your Form has been Submitted!";

}
?>
        <form action="http://www.copot.eu/matei/mail/index.php?savedata=1" method="post">
            Your Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Your Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Your Message:<br> <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I changed the links and added the YOURDATAFILE.txt to my webpage, so that it works on my page, but apparently it doesn't. I'll surely change it later to what I exactly need (when I'll be able to fully understand what's going on), but for now I literally copied and pasted what I found as an answer at http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=70644.0, and changed some of the links. I manually modified the file in which the data will be stored, so that I can see that the file exists (mail/YOURDATAFILE.txt). If you think something else is missing you can check the site (http://www.copot.eu/matei/mail) and see if anything else is missing. Another thing (optional): can someone tell me how the code works (and don't tell me to look at a tutorial please)?

When I try to submit the error says:

```
Warning: fopen(YOURDATAFILE.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\webs\copoteu\matei\mail\index.php on line 21
Couldn't open YOURDATAFILE.txt for writing!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your (ftp?) user and the user that executes the php (the web-server, a user like apache, www or something like that) are not the same. So if you add a file, there is no guarantee that the web-server / php can write to it. So you need to check the permissions of the file and / or change the ownership to the web-server user.

Apart from that you should really move your file out of your web-root as the whole world will be able to read it.

Comment: well, it's a simple txt, I looked at the properties and it said available to everyone. If it's an advanced property, please, tell me how. And for the fact that everyone that knows the link can find it... well, it's just a form, the fact that people can see what others wrote it's not a problem, but people may put personal information: is the best way of not making it available to strangers making a new branch with some random characters with the file in it?

Comment: @Cicada3301 `Available` is not the same as `writable`. It would depend on your server / operating system what exactly you need to check and do. And like I said, you should move the file out of the web-root.

Comment: can you send me instructions to do so? And also your solution to moving the file out of web-root. I'm 13, I understand many code languages and I'm able to write with them, but I don't understand how a server and a pc work in all of their properties

Comment: I added writeability to it, now it works, but what do you suggest for making it out of range of other users but the server owner?

Comment: @Cicada3301 You should move it out of the web-root, for example by using something like: `$file = "../../../data/YOURDATAFILE.txt";` The exact configuration depends on your server setup and what you have access to exactly. You could also put it in a sub-directory of `mail` and protect that directory with a password. Again, server-dependent.

Comment: For now I just renamed it to a random string in a sub-directory, but people can look at what the random string is by pressing F12, right? If so I think I'll add a password to that file... thanks a lot

Comment: snap! PHP doesn't show using F12, is there any way to check the PHP from a page, without having access to the php or html complete files? I noticed it hid the PHP, but not sure if there is a way to recover it and somehow get the directory of the file

Comment: @Cicada3301 No, if the name is defined in php, it will not show up in the html unless there is an error causing the php not to run. You should however remove it from your error messages just in case and replace that with a more general error message.

Comment: as I said, I don't really understand PHP, does that simply imply to make the `or die` code not display any variables? Sorry again for my lack of knowledge